# Count-Up Timer Required, iPhone Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, timer

I am new to iPhone programming so am hoping someone can help me out here. I have searched the web, but can only find information on count down timers.

What I am looking to do is start a count up timer when a button is pressed and then stop it when a certain value drops by, say 5, and finally display that time. I can display values on screen once I have them, but getting the time in the first place is proving difficult for me.

I apologize if this is a simple question, but I look forward to reading your responses.

Thanks in advance,
stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSDate` will provide the current date.  You can use `- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceNow`
to get the time since the first call and now.

Comment: Thank you Zaph, but could you maybe help me further by explaining how I could apply this method to my specific problem, Thanks stu

Comment: I need to know more about exactly you are trying to accomplish, how you are using time.

Comment: For a specific time in the future ypou can use NSTimer
    timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between an up-counter and down-counter.  Just change the order of your subtraction.

```
UpcounterElapsedTime = UpcounterCurrentTime - UpcounterStartTime;
DowncounterElapsedTime = DownCounterStartTime - DownCounterCurrentTime;
```